# Long list selector windows phone child control event in DataTemplate

Tags: windows-phone, longlistselector, childcontrol

I am searching for this long time and i couldn't get it.

I have a Long list selector in my windows phone 8 project.
How can i manage the button event in each item in the data template? I need to get the selected item in that button event. 
Code snippet shown below. Please help.

[image: code snippet]

Answer (score 0):

try this

// in your button click event type this code

var selectedValue = ((sender as Button).dataTemplate;

```
              or
```

var selectedValue = ((sender as Button).dataTemplate as SbCaDd).AcNo;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the dataContext then try this one.

XAML

```
<phone:LongListSelector Grid.Row="1"
                        Name="llsMsg"
                        LayoutMode="List"
                        VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel>
              <Grid>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                             Foreground="Black" />
                 <Button Content="View Details"
                         Width="200"
                         Click="Button_Click"/>
                </Grid>
             </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

C#

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dataContext = (sender as Button).DataContext;
    var dataContext = (sender as Button).DataContext as YourDataModel; 
}
```